# Risk Management - Working out the EF

Tags: risk-management

I've just started a risk management course at university and it is confusing the hell out of me.

So, we have a question that states the following:

> "An online marketplace has monitored their risk and found that over
>   three years there were 400 attempted DDoS attacks on their website. Of
>   those 400 attempts, five of them took the website offline. The value
>   of the whole website to the company per year is £1 million. For every
>   successful DDoS attack, the website would go down on average for one
>   day."
>
> What is the EF for the website going down for one day in a year, as a
>   decimal to six decimal places?

I'm so confused by this. I've been assuming that it has something to do with calcuating the 5 days by the three years it could happen but every answer I've given seems to be wrong.

Comment: Given that this is a homework question, I would suggest you to ask your professor about it. They will be able to explain it better to you, and it will also show that you care about learning.

Comment: We can help but we request that you explain how you answered it yourself, first.